# Loop through two raster datasets by order and perform a function

Tags: arcpy, raster, loop

I have two raster datasets that I need to loop through by order and select the first raster from the first dataset with the first raster from the second dataset to perform a function. I keep getting error 000732 raster dataset not found, but it does exist.
My code so far, I'm not an expert:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import*
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace= r'C:/Time slices/U_sqaurred'
Urasters= arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif*')
arcpy.env.workspace= r'C:/Time slices/V_squarred'
Vrasters=arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif*')



for idx in range(0, len(Urasters)-1):
    ras1= Urasters [idx]
    ras2= Vrasters [idx]
    outraster= SquareRoot (Raster(ras1) + Raster(ras2))
    outpath= "C:/Time slices/magnitude"
    outpath = outpath + ras1
    outraster.save(outpath)
```

Comment: could it be a problem to have spaces in folder names? Try to move your raster to a folder with no spaces in the name

Comment: I just renamed the folder and removed all spaces, but still same error: outraster= SquareRoot (Raster(ras1) + Raster(ras2))
RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset Jan_U_10_0.tif does not exist or is not supported

Comment: Try to remove the asterisk after .tif in : Urasters= arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif*')

Comment: The code runs without error when I remover the asterisk but there's no output

Comment: '*.tif' is correct usage, if you want to list just TIFFs.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you try the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `env.workspace` to `Vrasters` but trying to process the raster (name) coming from `Urasters` folder.  Your Raster(ras2) should be fine but the problem is with Raster(ras1). The  problem is that `ListRasters` just registers the file names in that folder, not their path! Change this to `Raster(os.path.join(r'C:/Time slices/U_sqaurred', ras1))` after importing `os` module.